# Is there a Vanilla JS alternative for the jQuery UI Dialog widget

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

Is there a Vanilla JS replacement for the dialog widget provided by jQuery UI?
It should at least allow to contain arbitrary markup, so alert or prompt are not an option.

Comment: `alert`, `prompt`, `confirm`

Comment: The internet is full of javascript dialogs/light boxes.

Comment: There's the [native HTML5 `<dialog>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dialog) but it's not supported on several important platforms.

Comment: I'd suggest making one. It is very easy to do, and should take no more than about 30 minutes. I'd suggest creating a few funcs. One func to hold your structure, with a param to feed your content and any conditions with the dialog you need. Another func for events, such as your click events, scrolling, loading, drag, resize, etc. And a 3rd possibly for any ajax you may need. You may even want a 4th depending on how you handle initializing the modal. Lastly, your CSS. A simple modal will have a basic HTML structure - usually a title bar, content body, and if necessary, a footer.

Comment: If you want a lightbox, the approach is similar to the modal, except that you don't usually want things like drag, and it usually has a backdrop. Otherwise, the approach is very similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only to a certain extend. You might use `alert`, `prompt` or `confirm` dialogs (implemented as functions on the `window` object), but they can't be styled and look different between various browsers.

Creating a special modal/dialog with vanilla JS is of course possible. How hard it is depends on the features you want/need it to have.